# use scapy sniff the icmp packet which is send to machine C by machine B at machine A

Tags: scapy, sniffer

I have 3 pc `(A,B,C)` and I wanna sniff the ICMP packet when I ping C at B.

```
(IP(A)=192.168.2.104,IP(B)=192.168.2.105,IP(C)=192.168.2.106 )
```

I use the python script like this:

```
from scapy.all import *
    def print_pkt(pkt):
        pkt.show()
    pkt = sniff(filter='icmp',prn=print_pkt,count=1)
```

but it doesn't work (i have set my card as promisc mode)
can you help me! thanks

Comment: I don’t really get the question :/ what do you mean by “ping C at B” ?

Comment: use command 'ping 192.168.2.106' at machine B, and I wanna sniff the ICMP packet at machine A

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want sniff packets between two device you should be in the middle of them, if you are and you're sniffing packets you should enable ip_forward feature. if you're using Ubuntu enable it this way :

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

Comment: if it works for you please mark it as answer my friend